# OpenCV - Create "own" canny filter

Tags: opencv, filter

i would like to create my own canny filter (to have a edge detection) by creating a kernel and apply it to my image as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("../Pictures/img.jpg");
    Mat img_cpy = img.clone();
    Mat kern = (Mat_<float>(5,5) << 2,4,5,4,2,
                                    4,9,12,9,4,
                                    5,12,15,12,5,
                                    4,9,12,9,4,
                                    2,4,5,4,2
                ) / 159;
    Point anchor = Point(-1,-1);


    filter2D(img_cpy, img, -1, kern, anchor, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);  //apply the filter  


    imshow("orig", img_cpy);
    imshow("res", img);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;

}
```

the thing is that i do not get the result i would like to have (binary image with white edges on black background)

what am i doing wrong / what do i need to add to my sample of code?

thank you a lot in advance

Comment: that's just the [gaussian kernel](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) ( used for blurring/smoothing ) . so, you only got step one of 5 (ofc. you should start with step 5 ;])